# How to use min & max in objective function in pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo, objective-function

I am very new to Pyomo, working on a use case where my objective function coefficient is dynamic & needs a min-max function.

Objective function = Max( sum (P * UC) - sum ( P - min(P)) * UC
where P is variable needs to be optimized and UC is function which is derived value based on some calculation.

I have few doubts

1. how to use min or max function in objective function, I have tried np.min or calling function but it gives error since function has if else condition

I have tried multiple things but none seems to be working. If someone can help me with dummy code that will be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"I have tried multiple things but none seems to be working."* But you didn't say what you tried, and you didn't say what went wrong. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Min could be implemented by defining a new variable `min_P`, which needs to be smaller than any of the `P`, expressed by constraints:

`min_P <= P[i]` for all i

This will make sure, that `min_P` is not larger than the smallest of the `P`. Then you can just use `min_P` in your objective function. I assume you know how to define constraints like this. This might result in an unbound variable problem, depending on how exactly you are optimizing, but this should put you on the right track.

The max case is analogous, if you define another value for the expression `sum (P * UC) - sum ( P - min(P))`.

It is not clear whether `UC` is a parameter or a variable itself (calculated in another constraint). In the latter case, the whole problem will be highly nonlinear and should be reconsidered.

I do not understand your AbstractModel vs ConcreteModel question. If you have the data available, use a ConcreteModel. Apart from that, see [here](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_overview/abstract_concrete.html).

Comment: Thanks for quick response, UC is nothing but function to calculate unite change. just to give you bit context I am looking at price optimization problem, if we increase price unit sold will also change based on certain formula, so UC is nothing but function which will return change in unit sold with change in Price

Comment: Another Question on min_p as variable with constrain, this will make sure min_p is not larger of smallest of P but in reality we need smallest P & not any other value smaller than that.  I have also tried to create that constrain but not sure how to do it  pyo.Constrain(expr = min_p <= [Pg[g] for g in model.IDX] ) throws an error list object has no attribute 'is_unmeric_type"

Comment: Yes, that might be a problem depending on what exactly you optimize. That's what I meant by "result in an unbound variable problem". If the problem were linear you could always use this approach, for non-linear problems I'm not sure. Your problem looks highly non-linear, if UC depends on the Price, which you optimize. You should first figure out the mathematical structure of the problem and check whether your solver is actually able to handle it.